# WMTS protocol and MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, wms

In my project there is a custom `server`, that gives `maps` `layers` in `WMTS protocol`. As far as it's custom, it cannot send layers in `TPK (ArcGIS extension pac )` format. Does `iOS` default `Map KIT` work with `WMTS` layers and how? Or does a `third-party` solution exists? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not natively. You can use an library called Route Me on github. It is a BSD license. https://github.com/Alpstein/route-me